# Are 55,400 people injured or killed by US police every year?

Tags: united-states, police

[An article](http://thefreethoughtproject.com/landmark-study-police-brutality-problem/) has been circulating around social media, claiming

> approximately 55,400 people were injured or killed by [US] cops during legal stop and search incidents in one year. Of this number, about 1,000 were killed, with vast majority dying from gunshot wounds. The remaining 54,400 were hospitalized with serious injuries, mostly from blunt objects.

The article cites [this study](http://injuryprevention.bmj.com/content/early/2016/06/16/injuryprev-2016-042023), which seems legit. However, I fear that the article may misinterpret or exaggerate the study's claims. **Are the article's claims substantiated by the study, and is the study's analysis/methodology valid?**

Comment: "Hospital treated injury" doesn't mean anything really happened--lots of suspects will claim injuries that didn't happen.  Beyond that, though--people sometimes resist arrest.  I don't find the numbers shocking.

Comment: And, being the U.S., many people will refuse treatment because not everyone is insured, or they may be afraid to seek help. You can speculate either way depending on your prejudices. Neither way is helpful with regards to the question.

Comment: that's only 17 people per 100,000 residents. that's not too difficult for me to believe.